# why can't the go-xorm print the error message

Tags: go, go-xorm

I use xorm to connect to my mysql database,but when my mysql doesn't start,xorm  cann't print error message

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "xorm.io/xorm"
)

var engine *xorm.Engine

func main() {
    var err error
    engine, err = xorm.NewEngine("mysql", "root:1234567@/blog?charset=utf8mb4")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())//can't print
        return
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Ping` method to check whether the database is alive

```
if err := engine.Ping(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

[Ping method](https://pkg.go.dev/xorm.io/xorm#Engine.Ping)

Comment: thanks,the problem is solved.what’s the  usage of err in my code，or  when i use it

Comment: I've updated the code on how to use the error. If my answer solved your issue, would you be kind enough to accept my answer.